# C# getting first digit of int in custom class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to build a help function in my guess the number game, whereby the user gets the first digit of the number he/she has to guess. So if the generated number is 550, he will get the 5.

I have tried a lot of things, maybe one of you has an idea what is wrong?

```
public partial class Class3
{
    public Class3()
    {
        double test = Convert.ToDouble(globalVariableNumber.number);
        while (test > 10)
        {
            double firstDigit = test / 10;
            test = Math.Round(test);
            globalVariableNumber.helpMe = Convert.ToString(firstDigit);
        }

    }

 }
```

Under the helpButton clicked I have:

```
    private void helpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       label3.Text = globalVariableNumber.helpMe;
        label3.AutoSize = true;
```

That is my latest try, I putted all of this in a custom class. In the main I putted the code to show what is in the helpMe string.

If you need more code please tell me

Comment: How about `test.ToString()[0]` instead?

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Are you having issues with rounding?

Comment: The problem is that I constantly end up with no text in the label I  want to show it in.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ToString the number and use Substring to get the first character?

```
var number = 550;
var result = number.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
```

If for some reason you dont want to use string manipulation you could do this mathematically like this

```
var number = 550;
var result = Math.Floor(number / Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number))));
```

Comment: When I use this I still end up with no text in my label where I want to show the first digit

Comment: I think you might be having trouble caused by something else. Perhaps you are not assigning the label text correctly? Maybe you could add some more of your code to the question to make it easier to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong - you have an infinite while loop there. Math.Round(test) will leave the value of test unchanged after the first iteration.
You may have intended to use firstDigit as the variable controlling the loop.
Anyway, as suggested by others, you can set helpMe to the first digit by converting to a string and using the first character.
As an aside, you should consider supplying the number as a parameter and returning the helpMe string from the method. Your current approach is a little brittle.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this, nice catch!

Comment: I couldn't believe it either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are doing the division and storing that in a separate variable, then you round the original value. That means that the original value only changes in the first iteration of the loop (and is only rounded, not divided), and unless that happens to make the loop condition false (i.e. for values between 10 and 10.5), the loop will never end.

Changes:

- Use an `int` intead of a `double`, that gets you away from a whole bunch of potential precision problems.
- Use the `>=` operator rather than `>`. If you get the value `10` then you want the loop to go on for another iteration to get a single digit.
- You would use `Math.Floor` instead of `Math.Round` as you don't want the first digit to be rounded up, i.e. getting the first digit for `460` as `5`. However, if you are using an integer then the division truncates the result, so there is no need to do any rounding at all.
- Divide the value and store it back into the same variable.
- Use the value after the loop, there is no point in updating it while you still have multiple digits in the variable.

Code:

```
int test = (int)globalVariableNumber.number;
while (test >= 10) {
  test = test / 10;
}
globalVariableNumber.helpMe = test.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Math.Round(), in your example, you're rounding 5.5 to 6 (it's the even integer per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx)).  Use Math.Floor instead, this will drop the decimal point but give you the number you're expecting for this test.

i.e.

```
double test = Convert.ToDouble(globalVariableNumber.number);
    while (test > 10)
    {
        test = Math.Floor(test / 10);
        globalVariableNumber.helpMe = Convert.ToString(firstDigit);
    }
```

Like @Sam Greenhalgh mentions, though, returning the first character of the number as a string will be cleaner, quicker and easier.

```
globalVariableNumber.helpMe = test >= 10 
                            ? test.ToString().SubString(0, 1) 
                            : "Hint not possible, number is less than ten"
```

This assumes that helpMe is a string.

Per our discussion in the comments, you'd be better off doing it like this:

```
private void helpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label3.Text = GetHelpText();
   label3.AutoSize = true;
}

// Always good practice to name a method that returns something Get...
// Also good practice to give it a descriptive name.
private string GetHelpText()
{
    return test >= 10    // The ?: operator just means if the first part is true...
           ? test.ToString().SubString(0, 1)   // use this, otherwise...
           : "Hint not possible, number is less than ten" // use this.
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you or your response, but when I try this code I end up with the same result as before. There is nothing in my label, where as you execpt that it will work. Even if I try this code in the main, it is not working.

Comment: Are you actually setting your label.Text to the value in globalVariableNumber.helpMe at any point?  If its a Console application, you need to Console.WriteLine() the new value whenever it changes.

Comment: Yes under the helpButton clicked event I have the following code:             label3.Text = globalVariableNumber.helpMe;
label3.AutoSize = true;

Comment: Part of the confusion here is your use of globals, why not make the code you've presented return the string instead of assigning it to globalVariableNumber, then just label3.Text = this.GetHelperNumber()

Comment: Could you help me how to return a code? I am very new in programming, this is my first try ever. And I've tried but I actually have no idea how to do it

Comment: Edited my answer to try to explain further

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It finally works :)